# Xcode: Is avoiding Interface Builder a good or bad idea?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am slowly learning how to build Apps in Xcode and Objective-C and Ive been reading [this blog post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder) about writing Cocoa Touch Apps without ever using the Interface Builder, and [this blog post](http://berzniz.com/post/32597579083/8-reasons-why-real-men-do-use-interface-builder) about how someone just uses Interface Builder whenever they can.

I find myself leaning more towards avoiding to use the Interface Builder, as I can find problems faster if its just plain code, and at this point I am more familiar with writing code than using the Interface Builder.

So I am considering avoiding to use the Interface Builder altogether. But before I do I wanted to know the following:

- Is there any time when you absolutely must use Interface Builder? Is there anything that is impossible to achieve without it? (I know the reverse is true.)
- Are there any practices I can employ to help me not miss out on the advantages Tal Bereznitskey outlines for using Interface Builder. I am specifically thinking of the points he makes about it being easier to maintain and easier to prototype and change stuff.
- Will ignoring the Interface Builder altogether put me at a disadvantage in anyway for building Apps in the future. Will the complex Apps that I hope to be working on in the future be significantly more difficult to develop if I just stick to writing code?
- I am currently just building Apps by myself, but when I start working with other developers will I be at a significant disadvantage because I never learnt how to use Interface Builder, or will I be able to get by just knowing how to write code?

Comment: IB is clumsy, but not as clumsy as trying to manage a large, complex layout with just code.  One important thing when using IB is to use the Document-> Label field to name everything (that isn't naturally named by its label value), so you can tell which element is which.  Also, keep elements in order and grouped in some logical fashion.  (Drag them around in the Objects view as needed.)  Of course, essentially the same rules apply to the code-only approach -- keep it neat, well-commented, and well-organized.

Comment: @Hotlicks but it's **still very clumsy** :) Wy worse than it should be.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Is there anything about Xcode that *isn't* clumsy?

Comment: @HotLicks No, there isn't, practically.

Comment: @mods - Although the subject matter of this is opinion-based, I tried my best to pose questions that were objective. I think it would be helpful for new comers to Objective C to know if there is any disadvantage to avoiding Interface Builder, or if avoiding it will cause problems later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience with development and the pros and cons of IB:

Start by letting IB remove complexity where it obscurs learning about core concepts expressible only in code. There is much to be said for the fact though that IB hides connections that would otherwise be obvious (and therefore easy to learn and debug), however generally it does a good job of removing extraneous code.

It's beneficial to learn as much as possible about the way view hierarchies and UI elements work without needing to use IB once you feel more comfortable with Objective-C and cocoa. I don't think there's anything you can't do in IB but theres certainly a lot that is more flexible and powerful when handled programatically.

From that point, once you understand the underlying functions then you can go back to using IB and let it save you time and energy you would otherwise use setting many many properties of UIKit elements.

To address your concerns about missing out. I'd say take some time to learn both Storyboards (a collective method of planning the UI) and XIB/NIB files (where a single file of UI is associated with a single view controller). Storyboards are newer and less perfectly understood by many people, including me! NIBs and XIBs are more powerful/less obvious but still very important as some things don't work so well in Storyboards.

In terms of working with others, IB can make version control a pain as the Plist/Backing of IB files doesn't always play nice with merging etc... However I'd say that if you're coming from a point of learning code first then moving to learn IB will be easier then the other way round. The most important rule of working in a team is to not be afraid to ask questions. Your code skills will help someone else who can in turn help you with IB.

Hope that helps.
There's great tutorials on the Ray Wendlerlich site, google him.

Comment: Thanks for the well balanced and thoughtful response. I will take your advice and stick to learning the code first, and once I have a good grasp of that, then I will start to seriously use Interface Builder. Its a shame that it makes app development feel clunky, but if it saves significant development time then I suppose its worth persevering with.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any time when you absolutely must use Interface Builder? Is there anything that is impossible to achieve without it? (I know the reverse is true.)

As far as I know, no.

> Are there any practices I can employ to help me not miss out on the advantages Tal Bereznitskey outlines for using Interface Builder. I am specifically thinking of the points he makes about it being easier to maintain and easier to prototype and change stuff.

Interface Builder has several advantages and disadvantages. Let me enumerate some of them:

Advantage #1: it's easier to quickly whip up moderately complex interfaces.

Advantage #2: as it's deeply integrated with development tools, you can be almost absolutely sure that it maintains consistency within the UI of your app. For example, I've experienced that when I've built a table view controller, I missed some slight detail in the code, and there was some extraneous empty space above the table view. This error didn't occur when I used IB.

Disadvantage #1: In the case of opensource libraries and apps, developers without IB (for example, those using an unofficial toolchain and/or those developing for jailbroken devices with e. g. Theos) won't be able to make use of your code fully.

Disadvantage #2: if you are a beginner with iOS development, you can easily become "lazy" and not learn how to build up a complete UI entirely from code. This is a very useful skill when composing highly dynamic interfaces with lots of small details.

> Will ignoring the Interface Builder altogether put me at a disadvantage in anyway for building Apps in the future. Will the complex Apps that I hope to be working on in the future be significantly more difficult to develop if I just stick to writing code?

The only disadvantage I can see is that at the beginning, writing the code from scratch may be slower than drag'n'dropping the widgets, but even this difference becomes small with time.

> I am currently just building Apps by myself, but when I start working with other developers will I be at a significant disadvantage because I never learnt how to use Interface Builder, or will I be able to get by just knowing how to write code?

In general, being able to use IB is an expected skill when working in a group, but my personal experince confirms that it's not that a big problem if you can't/don't use it. Last summer I've worked for an enterprise on a professional mobile banking app. I'm not very experienced with IB and I almost never use it, yet I was among the most productive developers.

Comment: its very encouraging to know that I can (and others do) get by without Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

The topic has been covered well already. Let me throw in my perspective succinctly.

In the early days of iOS development, Interface Builder was very buggy and avoiding it completely was a legitimate way of ensuring fewer bugs (and therefore save time).

The same is not true anymore. If you do everything from code, you'll spend 3 times more time creating user interfaces.

Also storyboards are an easy way of explaining screen flow to others.

Comment: "If you do everything from code, you'll spend 3 times more time creating user interfaces." - I think that's a personal preference :) A quick typer can be just as fast as someone using IB. Again, I'm not saying you're wrong and I don't want to solicit a debate either, just saying that coding is not necessarily slower.

Comment: Sure, what one is used to matters a lot. IMO, it's useful to have expertise in both approaches and adapt to the needs of the task.

Comment: @SanjazChaudhry Exactly. To be honest, I hate InterfaceBuilder, but I don't mind if someone likes it an uses it. (Well, not until I have to maintain his project anyway :P)