# xCode, Swift: working with vs. working without storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, toolbar

I'm new to programming apps, trying to realize a project for iOs using xCode and swift.

As far as I've learned most people seem to work with the storyboard feature, but I've come across people that suggest to deactivate the storyboard and work with code only.
I'd like to know your opinion on what method fits my needs best for the intended project. As I am just getting started, I'd like to stick with the appropriate method right away for I'm probably going to invest a lot of time.

This is about what the app is going to look like:

[myApp Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYBb.png)

Now this is what it' basically supposed to do:
The "settings"-button (blue area, top left) is going to take you to a different view to set preferences. The "search"-button (blue area, top right) is going to change the title into a search field.
You can browse through 3 categories. Each of them contains a couple of questions. Those are stored in a database and are supposed to be displayed list style within the red area. The order of the questions is going to depend on the users preferences.
Clicking any of the questions is going to take you to another view that displays the answer. When viewing the answer the "settings"-button (blue area, top left) is changing to a "go back"-button.

Now as far as I've learned the blue area might be realized with a navigation controller, navigation bar.
The white section works pretty much like a toolbar. However I've read it's close to impossible to move the standard toolbar from the bottom to the top.

I've seen tutorials of people realizing this type of layout with (to me) complex code but without using the storyboard. Am I wasting time on figuring out how to manipulate storyboard objects? Coming from coding and programming websites the project looks so unbelievably simple. Is a project like this in fact rather complex to do as an app?

Comment: Learn to do everything in code, then switch to xibs & storyboards. Try not to create any constraints manually (possible only activate/deactivate existing constraints or change their constant). Not using IB is like shooting yourself in the foot. It's your most powerful tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815618/xcode-is-avoiding-interface-builder-a-good-or-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

In any big project you will have to use all approaches, it is all about experience. For example, I am using `StoryBoards` to make 95% of my `UIViewControllers` elements, using `XIB` for static screens like error messages, some loadings etc. and using code to append some gradient views, shadows etc. It is possible that in future I will be doing all in a different way. But if you are a beginner - better use `Storyboard`, it makes getting into all of it much easier, understanding `UIKit` and iOS development overall.

Comment: Great thanks! Feels a lot better knowing what path to take! Intuitively I'd now try to learn how to...
1) manipulate a UINavigationBar so that it will behave like I want it to
2) try to find a way to place a UITabBar right underneath the NavigationBar
3) arrange the red content field as Table View
4) learn how to store data in a database and fill the cells of the table
Does this sound like this will lead me anywhere? Or is my intended project probably way above my head as a beginner?

Comment: it is always all about practicing, but I'd recommend to start with UI things, not DB, it is actually not that hard to make `UIViewController` like this one. If you would like to really study I would recommend to start with stanford cs193p, you can find it on iTunes. good luck